# Set containing another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

How can I state using *Set Notation* that each element $n$ in the set $A$ contains a *unique* set $B$ ?

Comment: $n$ contains a set $B$? Or $n$ belongs to $B$?

Comment: @Sigur you probably mean $B \in n$ instead of $n \in B$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson, my comment was based on a deleted comment by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\forall n\in A\,\,\exists ! B\,\,,\,B\,\,\text{is a set and}\,\,\,B\subset n$$

Comment: What does $$ B\subset n$$ mean in this context? That $B$ has fewer elements than the set $n$?

Comment: it means that B is a subset of n.

Comment: If $A$ is a set containing _cars_ and $B$ is a set containing _parts_ , then how can $B$ be a subset of $n$ ?

Comment: The above is *exactly* what you say:"Each **element** in A contains a **unique** set B" . As other comments say, I highly doubt this is what you *actually * meant, but that's not my problem.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that $B$ is an element of each $n\in A$, you can write $B\in\bigcap A$: for any collection $A$ of sets, by definition $x\in\bigcap A$ if and only if $x\in n$ for each $n\in A$. If you mean that $B$ is a subset of each $n\in A$, then each element of $B$ is an element of $\bigcap A$, and you can write $B\subseteq\bigcap A$.

There are of course more complicated ways to express the same things.